# Multithreading with google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there any way to run many functions (or the same function with different parameters) at the same time?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an other better way: Use ServerHandlers... Unfortunately, concerning my script (Sorting gmail by size) short time limits don't allow me to go faster.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, by triggering a function at 1 minute intervals where the time to run is > 1 minute (but under the 6 minute maximum) you'll certainly have multiple instances running. It can be hard to manage though: make sure you use the LockService if you're changing/writing to any shared resources and you need also to watch out for hitting 24hr compute time quotas.